# will dFdx optimize for single varying?

Tags: opengl, glsl

since `dFdx` must cover every single case,

I think it must be implemented like this pseudo code :

```
vecN dFdx( vecN )
{
  wait_for_other_to_reach_here();
  return calculate_difference();
}
```

but look, if we pass single varying variable, it is very simple. since varying does interpolate linealry.

example fragment shader :

```
in vec3 v_vertex;

void main()
{
// it must be same result for all fragments in one triangle
  vec3 dx = dFdx( v_vertex );
  vec2 dy = dFdy( v_vertex );
  vec3 normal = normalize( cross( dx , dy ) );
  ....
  ....
}
```

Comment: You probably could implement it that way from a compute shader, but fragment processing is scheduled in blocks of at least 4 pixels. A LOT of fragment processing needs gradient information (e.g. mipmap LOD bias, anisotropic filtering, etc.), not just the derivative instructions. So as long as you use fragment processing in the render pipeline instead of the compute pipeline--yes--there is an optimization going on behind the scenes.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, varyings don't interpolate linearily, unless you use the `noperspective` or `flat` interpolation qualifiers. Interpolation will be non-linear in screen space, due to the perspective correction (unless you use an orthogonal projection).

Second, why do you think a wait operation occurs at all? The fragment shaders are run *in parallel*, and GPUs make sure to always run fragment shaders at least on 2x2 pixel quads, in complete lockstep in the same warp/wavefront/SIMD-group, even if that would include pixels outside of the primitive. This means that the GPU can always calculate the derivates, without ever having to wait for neighbor fragments to catch up. Modern GL will even tell you if a fragment shader invocation is only a helper invocation outside of the primitive via the [`gl_HelperInvocation`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/gl_HelperInvocation.xhtml) input.